# Extract price from string array and sort by price

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need help determining the best way to extract the price value out of the strings in the array received from the API, and then reorder the array based on the lowest price values.

These are some of the data that I received from the API.

```
let luxcar_data = ["Ferrari70", "Bugatti45", "McLaren17", "Lamborghini41", "Rolls52",  "Aston30", "Koenigsegg19", "Pagani28", "Lamborghini36", ...];
```

The outcome should look like this.

```
[{name: "McLaren", price: 17},  {name: "Koenigsegg, price: 19}, .... , {name: "Ferrari", price: 70}]
```

Comment: interesting, but you can find this solution easily from other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) can be used to extract the name and price. [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be applied to transform each element of the array to an object with the name and price. Then, directly call [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and substract the prices in the compare function.

```js
let arr = ["Ferrari70", "Bugatti45", "McLaren17", "Lamborghini41", "Rolls52",  "Aston30", "Koenigsegg19", "Pagani28", "Lamborghini36"];
let res = arr.map(s => {
  const [, name, price] = s.match(/([a-z]+)(\d+)/i);
  return {name, price};
}).sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: const [, name, price] = s.match(/([a-z]+)(\d+)/i);
Could you please explain me about this?

Comment: @ミツオ It destructures the result from `match`. `name` is set to the value of the first capturing group (`([a-z]+)`), which is a sequence of letters. `price` is set to the value of the second capturing group (`(\d+)`), a sequence of digits. See [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: @Unmitigated, it was great and shortest answer. awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract digit and non-digit parts of the `luxcar_data` items. The output is sorted by passing the function that compares the prices.

```js
let luxcar_data = ["Ferrari70", "Bugatti45", "McLaren17", "Lamborghini41", "Rolls52",  "Aston30", "Koenigsegg19", "Pagani28", "Lamborghini36"]

  
let output = luxcar_data.map((car) => {
  let name = car.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''); 
  let price = parseInt(car.replace(/\D/g,'')); 
  return { name, price };
}).sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);

console.log(output);
```

- `/[0-9]/g` - matches any digit
- `/\D/g` - matches any non-digit charater.

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

```
let res_data = [];

luxcar_data.map((ele)=> {
  let patt = /([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)/g;
  res_data.push({name:ele.replace(patt, "$1"), price:parseInt(ele.replace(patt, "$2"))})
})

console.log(res_data.sort((a,b)=>a.price-b.price));
```

I'd appreciate it if you may verify my answer.